# How to disable admin access on new site registration for user in Multisite?

Tags: multisite, network-admin

I have a scenario where i have to implement custom dashboard which should have nothing to do with wordpress backend instead it is intended for business purposes. A user signs up on the main website for sub domain and on registration he is supposed to be taken to my custom dashboard. However, the user should not be able to access wordpress admin dashboard. Currently i am not sure where to make necessary editing, so i haven't done anything in that regard. Is there a way to do it using wordpress built in functionalities?

Comment: Which parts of this have you implemented, and which parts are you unsure of? it's not clear if you already have code that redirects the user on registration or not. What have you tried so far? Can you edit your question to include any code you're currently using? Or if you have none to state that you have none?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function admin_default_page() {
return '/new-dashboard-url';
}

add_filter('login_redirect', 'admin_default_page');
```